# Wordpress Taxonomy Order by Custom ACF Field in Taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

is there anyone who could help me if this is posible?

I have an Custom ACF Field under CPT Taxonomy for order purposes. Is it posible to override get_posts/query using pre_get_posts to pull all category and order it by the custom ACF field under CPT Taxonomy?

The custom field is pc_order ( ACF number field )

I tried pre_get_posts but it seems not working or do you have any solutions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This code might help. Make sure to replace 'your_taxonomy' with the actual name of your taxonomy.

```php
function custom_order_query($query) {
    if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()) {
        if (is_tax('your_taxonomy')) { // Replace 'your_taxonomy' with the actual taxonomy name.
            $query->set('meta_key', 'pc_order'); // Set the meta key to your custom field.
            $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num'); // Order by a numeric value.
            $query->set('order', 'ASC'); // Specify the order (ASC or DESC).
        }
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'custom_order_query');
```